# Inheritance and exceptions

Tags: c++, inheritance, data-structures, default-constructor

I have several inheritance class, but I do not know how to create a default constructor for that, the map fact is a map that includes ID name and other thing for a pokemon

```
class Pokemon {
public:
     Pokemon(){}
     Pokemon(std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> > &facts);
protected:
     std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> > facts_;
};

class Dragon: virtual public Pokemon {
public:
    Dragon() : Pokemon() {}
    Dragon(std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> > &facts);
};

class Monster: virtual public Pokemon {
public:
    Monster() : Pokemon() {}
    Monster(std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> > &facts);
};   

class Charmander: public Monster, public Dragon {
public:
    Charmander() : Pokemon(), Monster(), Dragon(){}
    Charmander(std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> > &facts);
};

class Charmeleon: public Charmander {
public:
    Charmeleon() : Charmander() {}
    Charmeleon(std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> > &facts);
};

class Charizard: public Charmeleon {
public:
    Charizard() : Charmeleon() {}
    Charizard(std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> > &facts);
};
```

I just want to know how to write the default constructor for the class.

My complier keeps showing errors that:

```
./List07.txt:10:10: error: no matching constructor for initialization of
  'Charmander'
POKENAME(Charmander)
~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:276:44: note: expanded from macro 'POKENAME'
#define POKENAME(type)  try { answer = new type(facts); } catch (int) {
                                       ^
./pokemon.h:148:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor)
      not viable: no known conversion from 'const std::map<std::string,
      std::vector<std::string> >' to 'const Charmander' for 1st argument
class Charmander: public Monster, public Dragon {
  ^
./pokemon.h:151:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: 1st argument ('const
  std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> >') would lose const
  qualifier
Charmander(std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> > &facts);
^
./pokemon.h:150:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments,
  but 1 was provided
Charmander() : Pokemon(), Monster(), Dragon(){}
^
```

Comment: What does `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>` represent again?

Comment: default constructor for *what*? You've already defined the default constructors...

Comment: This question has nothing to do with exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler tries to tell you what's wrong here:

> no known conversion from 'const std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> >'

So, apparently `facts` is const, but all your (extremely odd) constructors take a reference to non-const, so they cannot be used.

Comment: so how to make a change to my extremely odd constructors

Comment: If you want to pass a const map, the parameter should be a const reference. It's just extremely unusable to create a single object from an entire container. That's what is a bit "odd".

Comment: Oops - "unusable" should be "unusual". Very helpful spelling correction!

Answer (score 0):

Your error is pretty clear, clean up the mess and this is what you end up with:

**no known conversion from** '`const std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> >`' ...

**candidate constructor not viable**: 1st argument ('`const   std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> >`') **would lose const qualifier** `Charmander(std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> > &facts);`

You are passing a const object to a constructor which takes a non-const reference. Review your constructors which accepts the facts for const correctness.